# Jquery Autocomplete submit form on select - Why this code dont work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am newby on javascript/Jquery. Can someome tell me how write this code correctly?

The part of the code wont work is:

```
select: function (event) {
         $("#busca-site").val(item.title);
         $("#form-busca-site").submit();
    }
```

Complete code:

```
$('#busca-site').autocomplete({
valueKey:'title',
accents:true,
replaceAccentsForRemote: true,
source:[{
    url:"https://www.example.com/teste2/teste_search2.asp?q=%QUERY% ",
    type:'remote',
    getValueFromItem:function(item){
        return item.title
    },
    ajax:{
        dataType : 'json'   
    }

}],
select: function (event) {
         $("#busca-site").val(item.title);
         $("#form-busca-site").submit();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 1** - The original main code fully functional is:

```
$('#busca-site').autocomplete({
valueKey:'title',
accents:true,
replaceAccentsForRemote: true,
source:[{
    url:"https://www.example.com/teste2/teste_search2.asp?q=%QUERY% ",
    type:'remote',
    getValueFromItem:function(item){
        return item.title
    },
    ajax:{
        dataType : 'json'   
    }

}]
});
```

Comment: I do not see where `item` is passed to the Select event. Is this a jQuery UI Autocomplete?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: Actually is this plugin: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/

Comment: please update your answer with a full description and what's the plugin that you use, Is a jQuery UI Autocomplete?.

Comment: I am using this "Autocomplete like Google" plugin which is based on Jquery. Doing a research, I found some answer for this question, but was for the native Autocomplete Jquery. So i am trying to insert this piece of code `select: function (event) ` to the main function above

Comment: what does `event` has ? do `console.log(event)`

Comment: @Swati, console.log(event) does nothing in chrome console...

Comment: Hi, did you check that plugin there is `.on('selected.xdsoft',function(e,datum){alert(datum.id);alert(datum.title);});` you can use this .

Comment: Thank you @Swati! You save me! Post your answer please so I will choose as the solution.

Comment: You can answer your own question please do that it will help others  :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the @Swati tip that he observed the plugin has a built in function, the working code would be:

```
$('#busca-site').autocomplete({
valueKey:'title',
accents:true,
replaceAccentsForRemote: true,
source:[{
    url:"https://www.example.com/teste2/teste_search2.asp?q=%QUERY% ",
    type:'remote',
    getValueFromItem:function(item){
        return item.title
    },
    ajax:{
        dataType : 'json'   
    },
    
}]
}).on('selected.xdsoft',function(e,datum){
 //alert(datum.id);
 $("#form-busca-site").submit(); 
 //alert(datum.title);
});
```